# C7595 error after reinstalling visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, format, std

I recently reinstalled visual studio, and apon reinstalling and attempting to compile some code of mine that had compiled completely fine up until that point, I was met with an error related to constant expressions inside of std::format strings.

I am using a compile time string encryption library known as xorstring and have not previously encountered this error. A minimum reproduceable example is provided below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format>
#include <array>

namespace strenc
{

    constexpr auto time = __TIME__;
    constexpr auto seed = static_cast<int>(time[7]) + static_cast<int>(time[6]) * 10 + static_cast<int>(time[4]) * 60 + static_cast<int>(time[3]) * 600 + static_cast<int>(time[1]) * 3600 + static_cast<int>(time[0]) * 36000;

    // 1988, Stephen Park and Keith Miller
    // "Random Number Generators: Good Ones Are Hard To Find", considered as "minimal standard"
    // Park-Miller 31 bit pseudo-random number generator, implemented with G. Carta's optimisation:
    // with 32-bit math and without division

    template < int N >
    struct RandomGenerator
    {
    private:
        static constexpr unsigned a = 16807; // 7^5
        static constexpr unsigned m = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1

        static constexpr unsigned s = RandomGenerator< N - 1 >::value;
        static constexpr unsigned lo = a * (s & 0xFFFF); // Multiply lower 16 bits by 16807
        static constexpr unsigned hi = a * (s >> 16); // Multiply higher 16 bits by 16807
        static constexpr unsigned lo2 = lo + ((hi & 0x7FFF) << 16); // Combine lower 15 bits of hi with lo's upper bits
        static constexpr unsigned hi2 = hi >> 15; // Discard lower 15 bits of hi
        static constexpr unsigned lo3 = lo2 + hi;

    public:
        static constexpr unsigned max = m;
        static constexpr unsigned value = lo3 > m ? lo3 - m : lo3;
    };

    template <>
    struct RandomGenerator< 0 >
    {
        static constexpr unsigned value = seed;
    };

    template < int N, int M >
    struct RandomInt
    {
        static constexpr auto value = RandomGenerator< N + 1 >::value % M;
    };

    template < int N >
    struct RandomChar
    {
        static const char value = static_cast<char>(1 + RandomInt< N, 0x7F - 1 >::value);
    };

    template < size_t N, int K >
    struct XorWString
    {
    private:
        const wchar_t _key;
        std::array< wchar_t, N + 1 > _encrypted;
        bool decrypted = false;

        constexpr wchar_t enc(wchar_t c) const
        {
            return c ^ _key;
        }

        wchar_t dec(wchar_t c) const
        {
            return c ^ _key;
        }

    public:
        template < size_t... Is >
        constexpr __forceinline XorWString(const wchar_t* str, std::index_sequence< Is... >) : _key(RandomChar< K >::value), _encrypted{ enc(str[Is])... }
        {
        }

        __forceinline decltype(auto) decrypt(void)
        {
            if (!decrypted)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                {
                    _encrypted[i] = dec(_encrypted[i]);
                }
                _encrypted[N] = '\0';
                decrypted = true;
            }
            return _encrypted.data();
        }
    };
}

#define xorws( s ) ( strenc::XorWString< sizeof( s ) - 1, __COUNTER__ >( s, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof( s ) - 1>() ).decrypt() )

int main()
{
    auto str = std::format(xorws(L"this is a formatted string {}"), 1); // <- error here
}
```

You should get Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C7595   'std::_Basic_format_string<wchar_t,int>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
apon trying to run the program.

build log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test_app, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>test_app.cpp
1>C:\Users\throw\source\repos\test_app\test_app\test_app.cpp(98,25): error C7595: 'std::_Basic_format_string<wchar_t,int>::_Basic_format_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
1>C:\Users\throw\source\repos\test_app\test_app\test_app.cpp(74,142): message : failure was caused by out of range index 30; allowed range is 0 <= index < 30
1>Done building project "test_app.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

compiler information:

```
visual studio 2019 latest version
windows sdk version 10.22000
platform toolset v142
language standard /std:c++20
```

if this is an actual error with my code, what can I do to fix it, and why wasn't I encountering this error before, and if it isn't, what can I do to remedy my MSVC install.

Thank you!

Comment: done, but the error in this log is different from the errors I get when compiling my program, so I don't know if they are related.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked immediately, but at what lines do you get the errors? Please add comments on those lines in the shown code.

Comment: the only line giving an error is the use of std::format with xorws, should I call std::format with a normal string there would be no error, the string encryption code is 100% error free and works perfectly, it is only there so it can be used in the example.

Comment: You have two errors, one on line 98, one on line 74. I know I'm not going to count lines in your code, so *please* add comments on both those lines.

Comment: there is only one error, the other error does not exist in reality and is a fake error made up by msvc. This error changes depending on how the format is used. In the case of this example the error defies logic, claiming that an index of 30 is out of range of something that ranges from 0-30. The only error is on the only line of actual code in the program. Aka the first line of the main function.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-c7595-only-with-visualstudio-2022/1650148

Comment: No that error message is *very* relevant! You use `sizeof( s ) ` in your code, where `s` is a wide-character string. But you seem to have forgotten that `sizeof` returns the size *in **bytes***, not array elements. So on MSVC on Windows, that size will be `60` (because the string is 30 characters including null-terminator, and `wchar_t` is two bytes). That error leads to other problems.

Comment: This error does not exist when std::format decides to compile correctly. It is not relevant to the problem at all.

Comment: This is most likely a bug with the recent updates to std:c++20 with visual studio release 16.11.14. I will downgrade my version and report back.

Comment: You haven't considered that it might be a bug in the *older* versions of MSVC that now has been fixed? Bugs goes both ways.

Comment: Confirmed compiles completely fine on 16.11.5 (and works if you print or mess with the string). Why would a "bug" cause things to work perfectly and then now that its "fixed" cause them to not work at all. Makes no sense. And again further proof that secondary error is completely unrelated, if you set a variable to the xorws macro, and then use the variable inside of std::format, you get this response from the compiler as the secondary (fake) error "failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime" instead of the one about indexs. These are completely made up errors.

Comment: One of the problems with UB (which out-of-bounds access leads to) is that it might seem to work fine. The keywords there are *might seem*. That a program builds and runs doesn't mean it's correct, especially if it has UB. Since you use `sizeof` to get the byte-size of the string, are you *sure* you will not go out of bounds of the string? Perhaps that's the "bug" that was added to the later version of MSVC, that it adds an actual check for that (if you now consider that a bug).

Comment: read my above comment with edits, changing the code slightly generates wildly different errors from the compiler. Try this ```int main()
{
 auto our_decryped = xorws(L"this is a formated string {}");
 auto str = std::format(our_decryped, 1);
}``` The output of the build log is ```failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime and see usage of 'our_decryped'``` this makes no sense as "our_decrypted" is simply a wchar_t * Also if you read the code behind the string encryption it does not contain any out of bounds errors and has never caused out of bounds issues for me.

Comment: also the issue you pointed out with sizeof is not present in the non wide version of the encryption, but the std::format issue still persists. This is an unrelated problem and does not effect the error generated about constant expressions. I do not care that an array allocates 30 more bytes than required. I care that my program (which compiled and worked before this update) compiles and works again. Fixing the size allocation will not fix this error.

Comment: As an aside, `RandomGenerator` should implement the same methods as other random generators in the standard library, such as [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine).  Then, you can use a builtin distribution to generate random numbers with your engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the recent update to the Microsoft's STL, `std::format` now requires 100% constant values, but they have added `std::vformat` for runtime strings. I did not know this feature was added. If you have run into similar issues, try using `std::vformat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same behavior (gcc & clang are ok).

Minimal example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c7ejsM6eh

Filed bug @msvc-dev: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C7595-error-on-valid-code/10150938

My impression - MSVC consteval support wants a huge lot to desired.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your issue isn't the same as OP's.