# parsing time format problem after update VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

My code worked fine, then i updated my VS and the same code stopped working.

```
struct TimeFormat
{
public:
    TimeFormat(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint, std::string format = "{:%Y-%m-%d %X}")
    {
        currentTimePoint = timePoint;

        timeStr = std::format(format, std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(currentTimePoint));
```

`std::format` doesn't get argument `std::string format`

```
C7595   "std::_Basic_format_string<char,std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::local_t,std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::system_clock::rep,std::chrono::system_clock::period>>>::_Basic_format_string": calling an immediately called function is not a constant expression
```

This code works fine!)))

```
timeStr = std::format("{:%Y-%m-%d %X}", std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(currentTimePoint));
```

Comment: The format string needs to be a constant expression.

Comment: The `std::format` has been "improved" with compile time verifications of the format string. Of course then requires a compile time constant string. [P2216 std::format improvements](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html)

Comment: Code snippet works fine for me. Try to create a new project.

Comment: @Minxin Yu - MSFT It's worked previously, before update VS(((. Now it doesn't work( current version 17.2.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C7595 error after reinstalling visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314203/c7595-error-after-reinstalling-visual-studio)

Comment: @MSFT I can't use std::vformat ((( as previous TS. Reinstall VS is not exit of my situation.